# YML organnized by controller and view. How can I DRY my YML file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
ptbr:
  # Chaves de tradução comuns a muitas views
  views:
  defaults:
    sign_in: Login
  sessions:
    sign_in: Login now
    new:
```

Suppose I've got the yml above. It doesn't work, but I just want to show my problem. I'm organizing my locale file by controller and views. I want, for instance, to be able to declare the sign_in key as default for any view in any controller. And to be able to override that value if I declare it again (making the rule more specific). It this case, all the views in any controller will understand t(.sign_in) as Login, **except the views in sessions controller**. Any idea of how to achieve that ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing it. The easiest way is to declare `@sign_in = t(default.sign_in)` inside your `ApplicationController`, and inside your `SessionsController` you overwrite as `@sign_in = t(sessions.sign_in)`.

This way you can keep the same view template for both. If this changes a link text, it would look like this:

```
<%= link_to @sign_in, sign_in_path ... %>
```

Another solution, if this text only shows inside the header of the website, would be to render a specific header for just this sessions view. Although I find this horrible, if you just want to change a simple text-field.